# I want to list out directory in a particular folder but i want them with a number listed before their names

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, directory

I am making a program where i have to choose a directory name but i don't want user to type the directory name instead of name they can choose numbers I am using Windows

I tried with below but it just print directory names. I want it with numbers before the names

```
os.system('dir /b')
print('Please choose the Existing Project to work on...,')
project_name = input('>')
```

1. folder_name_1
2. folder_name_2
3. folder_name_3

Comment: Create a list to hold the names and use the list index (or list index plus 1 to base it on 1) as the number. You can display both to the user. When the user enters a number you can then index the list with that number to get the name.

Comment: Can you give an example please ?

Comment: The answer that @joe-fivefifty gave already shows you how to create the list of files using `enumerate`. You just have to save that list and when the user picks a number, use the number to index the list. Start to work with it a bit, you'll figure it out and learn a lot in the process. :)

Comment: Thanks man i did it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
for index, folder_name in enumerate(os.listdir('/path/to/dir')):
    print(index, folder_name)
```

Comment: Better to use string formatting: `print("{}. {}".format(index, folder_name))`